# Assign a gesture to a key combination?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, touchpad, gestures

Anyone aware of a software that supports gestures and allows you to assign a key combination to them?

I'm using a similar program to spaces on windows, and i'd like to swipe to view a new desktop, I've found a few programs that allow you to do this.  But not with a gesture, anyone know a program available to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [TouchMe Gesture Studio](http://microsoft-news.com/customize-your-very-own-touchscreen-gestures-on-your-windows-8-device-using-touchme-gesture-studio-its-awesome/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20msftnws%20%28Microsoft%20News%29&utm_content=FaceBook) =]

It will let you assign touchscreen gestures to hotkeys. But it's only for touchscreens, not touchpads.